# Intellij multi-module project don't process resources folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, resources

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.6 (Community Edition) 
I've created multi-module project with one parent module and 2 child modules. The idea of mulit-module came to me after I was struggling with monolith application so I've rebuilded it. At that point there was no problem with resource folder, liquibase or banner. After this separation my **Liquibase** library stopped working, and **banner** stopped showing up.

Screenshots:

[image: project structure]

[image: Maven plugins]

Current structure of my project is:

**Parent

|----Child A

|----Child B**

Also in process of lunching any of child modules no target folder is generated, only 'out' file in parent module which contains only pom.xml, docker-compose.yml, .env and .idea files.

This issue with resources causes my banner not to show up and liquibase throwing error: **"Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml'"**
Looks like the whole resource file is 'missed' in process.

Temporary solution to this problem is to reimport child modules but problem returns.

**EDIT:**
I've specified in pom.xml resource file localisation and it still doesnt work.
[pom resources config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFiz8.png)

Comment: try to change db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml to db.changelog/db.changelog-master.yml'

Comment: This didnt work. As i mentioned the problem is not strictly about liquibase but resources file detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution to that error. In this case I manually decided to set packaging to pom in pom.xml file. That causes distrubance in application building process. So to make it work I had to delete:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```